# Prevent access to specific drives from My Computer in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I need to restrict access to all drives in My Computer.

My users must work only with storage provided via Folder Redirection and two mapped drives.

I know how to do it by by editing the registry files on a local computer, but I need to do this from Group Policy.

I saw a method by modify system.adm ... i search for it .. but i didn't find it in "%SystemRoot%\Sysvol\Sysvol\YourDomainName\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\Adm\System.adm" on windows server 2008 R2.

I hope that someone can help me as I need it as soon is possible.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on this configuration. Are you the system administrator? Is this server on a domain? Is it just a member server or a domain controller?

Answer (score 5):

The two policies that are probably going to help you the most are in:

User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer

Hide these specified drives in My Computer

Prevent access to drives from My Computer

Comment: Did this solution work?

Comment: @rabbid Can't speak for the OP, but my answer is correct ;)

Comment: These policies are only for RDP users? If logged on locally will policies take effect?

Comment: @rabbid No, they're for any user. Policies applied are the same regardless of logon type.